# How to implement JSQViewController UI with MultipeerConnectivity Framework?

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, multipeer-connectivity, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I have a fully functional Multipeer Connectivity app that allows me to browse the connected devices via Bluetooth and wifi, I have tried to implement the **JSQViewController** UI by installing the pod and creating a bridging-header.h file to import and thus, I have been able to create the UI with no problem whatsoever but the Multipeer Connectivity framework seems to not be working.

In the **JSQViewController** UI which includes the standard "send" button, it has been nearly impossible to create the "browse" button for the **Multipeer Connectivity Framework** that segues into a UITableView to connect with (an)other device(s). How best should I approach this in my view controller file? How would I subclass the class that has my **Multipeer Connectivity Framework** and my **JSQViewController** import in another class + file ?

Any suggestions on what should be done? I've searched everywhere and have done quite a few tutorials in relation to this and have found myself stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thing you are doing to much. When adding the JSQMessagesViewController to your project you do not need a bridging bridging-header.h it should not be added in that. If you look at the getting started guide there is a Swift example in the project itself.

```
 `Swift Example can be found in the SwiftExample folder just open the SwiftExample.xcworkspace.
```

Run pod install first.`

its a good example on how to implement JSQ in a swift project.

Once you have that set up and running looking into overwriting the toolbar to allow you to have a browse should be easier. Let me know when you have gotten to that point and ask any related toolbar button questions and I will try to answer them for you.

Hope that helps let me know if I can do anything else.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not exactly sure why I needed a bridging-header.h file either as I've made other apps with JSQMessagesViewController before but for some reason this tutorial (https://learnappmaking.com/messagecenter/) added it on. +1 for the pointers.

Comment: Ya I have seen it cause problems when it's added to he bridging header

Comment: Why do so many tutorials emphasize the need for a bridging header if it causes so many problems? I'm a bit on the fence on whether I should add one or not to this new project I'm working on ☹️

Comment: It comes with the understanding of what the bridging header file's purpose is. It is actually to let your objective c classes see your swift classes. So if you have a swift project with objective c frameworks included you don't necessarily need it. The reason so many tutorials suggest it is because they don't know what it is for but since they used it once before they add it "just in case". It gets a little convoluted when you read through apples documentation also. But the root of the problem is that there are a few ways to do things but doing them multiple ways can also make both not work.

Comment: I would suggest no bridging-header if at all possible. Which most of the time it is.

Comment: @DavidLeonard Do you know how I'd be able to pass any data from JSQMessagesViewController into a TableView cell?

Comment: @Alex7 I don't know if I understand your question full so if not let me know but you can just user `overwrite tableview(cellForRowAtIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {  //Code for creating your cell     } just like a normal table view.

Comment: What kind of information are you trying to pass in.

Comment: Pretty much just strings from the bubbles.

Comment: As in text for the message bubble.

Comment: Ahh I meant `CollectionView(itemForCellAtIndexPath)`

Comment: So what you want to do is make sure that your messages conform to the `JSQMessage` protocol and then just implement `override func collectionView(collectionView: `JSQMessagesCollectionView, messageDataForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> JSQMessageData {
        return messages[indexPath.item]
    }` messages is the list of messages ie the datasource.

Comment: So what you want to do is make sure that your messages conform to the `JSQMessage` protocol and then just implement `override func collectionView(collectionView: `JSQMessagesCollectionView, messageDataForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> JSQMessageData {
        return messages[indexPath.item]
    }` messages is the list of messages ie the datasource.

Comment: Okay so you know when you're checking your inbox in your iMessages and you see your conversation list from all the people you've been texting? I want to know how I can show those conversations on tableviewcontroller, does that make sense?

Comment: Ya you described it you need a "conversations list" which is just populated with all of your conversations. I don't know if you have a question on a specific piece. You just need a list of your conversations which will be different depending on how you are storing the data.